# Field 'subcategorytwo' doesn't have a default value yet, its has post data with value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am trying to add form data to mysql db. There're all data, yet its says that Field 'subcategorytwo' doesn't have a default value. Actually, there is also field of `subcategorytwo` in it. just check my error and screen shot with data.

The error that I got:

[image: Error while posting data]

The values that I have posted:

[image: Values Dumped]

Database:

[image]

Comment: Better show a code how you're saving it in DB, it seems you're not inserting subcategorytwo field

Comment: please provide view and controller code please

Comment: Let me here DD screen for you, @matiit

Comment: you have to list subcategorytwo in your query explicitly and assign it a value. Or alter the table and give the field a default value (null or value)

Answer (score 0):

You must either define a default value like this:
`ALTER TABLE posts MODIFY COLUMN subcategorytwo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';`
Assuming your field is varchar and you want it to default to string.

You can also just make it nullable
`ALTER TABLE posts MODIFY COLUMN subcategorytwo VARCHAR(255) NULL;`

Third option is just to supply the value
You are getting the error because you have to set `$post->subcategorytwo` and it requires a value.

Comment: I have add screen of `DB` table structure also. @Talifhani Luvhengo

Comment: now i have added `COLUMN subcategorytwo VARCHAR(255)` and I dont want subcategorytwo as `null` but i tested it when i do `null`, form data storing sucussfully but subcategorytwo is NULL. I have check `$request->subcategory_id` has value.

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed a Laravel application your best practice is to use the migration files through Artisan and use  ->default(val) for the column in question .